# Replaced my water heater and now I have very low water pressure both hot and cold

Tags: plumbing

I replaced my water heater and now there hardly any water pressure in both hot and cold. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you re-open the supply valve all the way?  Check it again.

Comment: See Paul Logan's answer - most likely a bit of solder from the replacement. This is probably happening in one of your faucets or could be more than one (but that would be unlikely - unless plumber was really really zealous with the soldering) .

Answer (score 4):

Clean the aerators on the faucets.

Comment: Right to the punchline. Indeed, the most likely cause. Also make sure the main supply valve is open all of the way ;)

Comment: Theory of this being that replacing a hot water heater is likely to slough off a bit of crap from the copper lines that would get strained out by aerators. If your tub faucet has the same problem then it might be something else (instead or in addition)